# Methods to copy form values from one form to another?

Tags: html, firefox, forms, copy, imacros

I need to copy values from a form displayed in one HTML page (incoming.html) to another HTML page (outgoing.html) in a browser. What will be the best approach to this, I have tried using imacros but have not been able to figure it out. I believe there can be a javascript solution to the above. What can be the best approach, I need the feature in a prototype and hence efficiency does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to use a server scripting language. You can pass values between two HTML pages in 2 ways. 
First, storing them in cookies using Javascript. If cookies are not enabled, then it would be a problem.
Second, Passing Values through the URL like PHP, but this method is not very secure if your using information that you do not want the user to view.

For eg: 
 `a href='something.htm?Something=Passing some variables'`

You can fetch them in the next page using Javascript and display them.

Comment: Both the form's are not in my control.